# Creating a custom React Hook

Tags: reactjs

I'm not very familiar with creating custom hooks, but what I would like to acheive is to create a function that takes in a file, which is then uploaded to firebase.

It would look like:

```
const UseUpload = (file) => {

  const [fileInfo, setFileInfo] = useState({
    fileUrl: '',
    progress: 0, 
    error: '',
    fileName: '',

   })
 const handleUpload = () => {

let file = e.target.files[0]
    if(file) {
    const storageRef = firebase
    .storage()
    .ref(`songs`)
    .child(file.name)
    const task = storageRef.put(file)
    task.on(
      "state_changes",
      function progress(snap) {
        setLoading(true);
        const percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;
          setFileInfo({
         ...fileInfo, 
         progress: percentage 
       })
      },
      function error(err) {
        setFileInfo({
         ...fileInfo, 
         error: err
       })
      },
      function complete() {
        storageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
              setFileInfo({
               ...fileInfo, 
               fileUrl: url,
               fileName: file.name
            })
        });
       
      }
    )
    }
  }
  return fileInfo

}
```

SO basically what this does, is it takes in a file from an `input type=file` and then returns the fileInfo state.
Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: Presumably your hook should return `handleUpload`, and then the caller attaches that to appropriate DOM. You might consider using a component to achieve this, though, in which case you can add DOM directly.

Comment: I prefer having it as just logic and not HTML because I  might want to change the design of the uploader